# Android phones: how does the video out feature work?

Tags: android, video

I'm searching for android phones that can use video out to the tv for a research project. I'm considering the HTC Touch Pro.

Is there anything I have to do specifically to get the video out to work (for displaying my app on the tv)? or will the phone just display a running app on the tv without extra work?

Thanks, I hope the post made sense =)

Answer (score 1):

HTC Touch Pro is not an android phone. As far as video out - Sprint upcoming EVO will have HDMI out connector.

Comment: Oh haha. I just need a smartphone with a touch screen and video out capabilities through composite video.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it will just work without any extra programming efforts on my part. Found out through youtubing.